# sql loop or self join

Tags: sql, scd

I have a dimension table that is a type 2 scd like this:

| Empl | job_id | old_job_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 101 | 98 |
| 12345 | 120 | 101 |
| 12345 | 130 | 120 |

I need to know the current job_id like this:

| Empl | job_id | current_job_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 101 | 130 |
| 12345 | 120 | 130 |
| 12345 | 130 | 130 |

can this be done with a sql query in a view?

I have tried a self join but that doesn't give me the current view for all records and there is not easy way I can think of to identify how many old jobs an employee has.

Also, I found another related issue.
|job_id | old_job_id | job_desc|
|-----|--------|---------------|
|100| NULL| CEO|
|110| NULL| Regional Mgr|
|120| 110| Regional Manager|
|130| NULL| Salesperson|

I'm looking to have this
|job_id | Current_job_id| Current_job_desc|
|-----|--------|---------------|
|100| 100| CEO|
|110| 120| Regional Manager|
|120| 120| Regional Manager|
|130| 130| Salesperson|

thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Never the loop. If there's alternative to a loop in SQL, (and there pretty much always is), you should take it. In this case, that alternative is called a **Recursive CTE**.

Comment: Can you use a windows function... `select empl, job_id, max(job_id) over (partition by empl) as current_job_id from my_data`

Comment: @Isolated with the sample data provided, yes. But I suspect there could be multiple chains per employee, which would invalidate that option. It is worth asking the question, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like :

```
WITH 
T AS 
(
 SELECT Empl, job_id, old_job_id, 0 AS DEEP
 FROM   "I have a dimension table" AS TR
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                  FROM   "I have a dimension table" AS TP 
                  WHERE TP.old_job_id = TR.job_id)
 UNION ALL
 SELECT T.Empl, TF.job_id, TF.old_job_id, DEEP + 1
 FROM   T  
        JOIN "I have a dimension table" AS TF
           ON T.Empl = TF.Empl AND TF.old_job_id = T.job_id
),
F AS
(
 SELECT Empl, job_id, old_job_id, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Empl ORDER BY DEEP DESC) AS N
 FROM   T
)
SELECT J.Empl, J.job_id, F.job_id  
FROM   "I have a dimension table" AS J
       JOIN F ON J.Empl = F.Empl
WHERE  N = 1;
```

Please respect the post chart by giving table's DDL and some INSERT to reproduce your trouble...

Comment: Thanks SQLpro. that works.  I just found another related issue. Not sure why these tables were setup this way.  Same idea but without the employee ID.